# Xamarin Reflection Assembly.LoadFile not supported

Tags: c#, xamarin, reflection, .net-assembly

i´m looking for an fixing of this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: "Assembly.LoadFile is not supported in AppX."

I´ve got an Xamarin-Project and i ´m trying to create an instance of a type of mine. all in all it looks like this:

```
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("MicroChatsTest.dll");
        var type = typeof(IUpdate);
        var mytypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (mytypes == null) throw new Exception("E1234");


        var whatever = Activator.CreateInstance(mytypes);
```

the error comes in the first line, because AppX/Xmarin doesn´t support the Assembly.LoadFile, is there any possibillity to fix this? thanks a lot.

Comment: Only on Android would you be able to do this, Apple forbids non-app-signed code from being loaded/JIT'd at runtime. UWP enforces a similar restriction.

Comment: How about adding a regular reference to this assembly?

Comment: What do you mean by "regular reference"?

Comment: Just a reference using visual studio. right click on project, add reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot load non-AOT compiled assemblies in Xamarin:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2294/assembly-load-is-it-possible

Comment: @SKirchner What OS does this error occur on? iOS or Android?

Comment: for now, i was debugging to UWP

Comment: @SKirchner please refer to the thread I linked you to, they discuss potential workarounds there.