# Xamarin Loading & Updating .dlls from Server

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I wonder if it's ok on the Xamarin platform on both IOS/Android to download .NET .dll from my own server and load it and execute the code inside.

1. Is it technically possible or are there any special code signing requirements related to IOS/Android?
2. Is there a Terms of Service policy that Apple and Google wouldn't allow this?

Comment: this is impossible on iOS.  The ipa package is cryptographically signed and cannot be modified

Comment: Does the signed ipa package prevent you from Assembly.LoadFile("my.dll") ? I don't think so, does it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106786/xamarin-reflection-assembly-loadfile-not-supported/54106879